# 500 error when connect to network.The carrier is XL Axiata in Indonesia

Tags: android, networking

When I analysis my app's http error data in Indonesia.I find a lot of users occurs 500  error when connect to network.The carrier is XL Axiata in Indonesia.I send a request,but the request never reach my server. Meaning the proxy in telecommunication provider block the request and give HTTP 500 error.Any body know why?

Answer (score 0):

You can try use https.

Some telco provider interrupt the network connection by showing interstial Ads before forwarding to intended web server. 
If the traffic using https, they can't interupt the traffic but just forwarding request to web server

Comment: So how you solve the problem .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696400/ion-cant-be-used-if-using-gprs-connection ?  Why  telco provider give HTTP 500 error?

Comment: Have you try https ? How is the result ?

Comment: My server doesn't support https now. I know the https may solve this problem.I still want know when the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696400/ion-cant-be-used-if-using-gprs-connection occur, why telco provider give HTTP 500 error and what's you solution?